# How to boot installer partition

Tags: backup, partition, high-sierra, hfs

I have created a macOS High Sierra install USB as a backup for my Mac and Windows. I want to be able to use one 16GB USB drive for my Windows and Mac. I think that this is possible using [Clover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/).

I have downloaded the macOS High Sierra installer using dosdudes1.com app and I have used [Install Disk Creator](https://macdaddy.io/install-disk-creator/) to create a 7.5GB HFS partition. I have installed Clover on the EFI partition that contains the Windows install but Clover will not find this install partition.

How do I find out what is going on and why will it not boot this partition?

Comment: It’s always best to download the installer from the App Store.

Comment: Hold Option at boot?